ACF Multiple Relationship query box
I use ACF to built a theme for my hiking blog... To be short each Hike(CPT) can have many Summit(CPT) and each Summit(CPT) has 1 Location(CPT).
When I add a Hike, i can add 1 or many summit in the box. That part work great.  But for example if in one Hike i've had to choose Black Mountain, i face off with multiple "Black Mountain" choice without knowing which one is the good. I would like to show the location next to the Summit Name.
What I've so far
 add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/result/name=sommet_rel', 'id_relationship_result', 10, 4);
function id_relationship_result($title, $post, $field, $post_id){
 
    $location = get_field('location', $post->ID);
    $title.= ' ' .  $location->$post_title;
    
    return $title;
} 

My structure
Hike ( Custome Post Type)

Summit (Bi-directionnale relationship)

Summit (custom Post Type)

Hike (Bi-Directionnale relationship)

Location (Relationship)


Location (Custom Post Type)
I know that for the filter i'm in the good place because when I put some hard coded values it's ok...  But there's is now way to dig into the relationship.
I've try to var_dump many value with no success.
I'm lost on this one and there is very little information on the net about this filter.

I'm lost on this one and there is very little information on the net about this filter.

I see what you're trying to do. You want to show the location alongside the summit name in the relationship field to differentiate between multiple summits with the same name.
Your code is almost there, but there's a minor error. You're attempting to access the $post_title property of the $location object, which isn't correct. Instead, you should use get_the_title($location->ID) to retrieve the title of the location post.
add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/result/name=sommet_rel', 'id_relationship_result', 10, 4);
function id_relationship_result($title, $post, $field, $post_id){
    $location = get_field('location', $post->ID);
    $title.= ''. get_the_title($location->ID). ')';
    return $title;
}


Thank you @Nimesh Sangada ! It's a good start and I understand that I must dig one step more into relationship to access the good value..  But with your code I've got error. The first thing i've done is to remove the ending $post-ID on the $location line.  That was better but with only the summit name and bracket after (): Ex: Black Mountain () ...  and on the right part of the Query box i've got this error: warning attempt to read property "ID" on array.

A little search on the net tell me to add an index to the $location[0]->ID.  That was working!!! BUT only for the right side of the Query box.... It's working only for summit that are selected. Summits on the left side still show as "summit ()"    That make no sense for me... :/

@F.Soucy,
Thanks for your effort! I saw your issue and I experimented locally. I found the solution!
Here is the updated code:
add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/result/name=sommet_rel', 'id_relationship_result', 10, 4);
function id_relationship_result($title, $post, $field, $post_id){
    $location = get_field('location', $post->ID);
    $title .= " (".$location[0]->post_title.")";
    return $title;
}


